# Excel VBA To Use Between In Where Clause

Tags: sql, vba, excel

How can I use two dates in my where clause.  The compiler keeps giving me errors about syntax.  What do I need to alter in this syntax to use my where clause

```vb
Sub Get_Data()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL, strInput As String

strFile = "A:\Test\de.accdb"

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strFile

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

d1 = InputBox("Input Start Date")
d2 = InputBox("Input End Date")

strSQL = "SELECT NAME, Location From db 1WHERE orderdate between ""'d1'"" AND ""'d2'"" Order By Location ASC;"

cn.Execute strSQL

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: There's a 1 before the word WHERE and you need to append the variables d1 and d2 to your string using ampersands.

Answer (score 2):

```
strSQL = "SELECT NAME, Location From db WHERE orderdate between '" & d1 & "' AND '" & d2 & "' Order By Location ASC;"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you've forgotten the `FROM` function in the query and you need to separate out the d1 and d2 with ambersands, try this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT NAME, Location FROM [name of table] WHERE orderdate between '" & d1 & "' AND '" & d2 & "'"
```

Comment: Sorry I have the from cluase in my syntax.  This gives me an error of escape convert error